# Function fails randomly

Tags: solidity, contract-design

In my contract I have a function that allocates funds to a bunch of shareholders according to their respective shares. Not sure why it reverts. The strange thing is it used to work some 3 months ago and I just copied the code into a new contract which fails 8 out of 10 times. Both arrays have the same length.

```
address payable[] public team;
uint256[] public shares;

function dividends()public payable{
    uint256 total = address(this).balance;
    for (uint8 i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
        team[i].transfer((total * (shares[i] * 100)) / 10000);
    } 
}
```

Comment: oh, thats the kind of function that confuse `estimateGas` haha. try bumping the gas limit up :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter.  I took it all the way up. Also fails in Javascript VM, in Remix

Comment: do you have a failed transaction hash? also if you're sending ether to contracts check their fallback function